# Best way to get last identity inserted in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, identity

Which one is the best option to get the identity value I just generated via an insert? What is the impact of these statements in terms of performance?

1. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`
2. Aggregate function `MAX()`
3. SELECT `TOP 1` IdentityColumn FROM TableName `ORDER BY IdentityColumn DESC`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** if you are inserting a single row and want to retrieve the ID that was generated.

```
CREATE TABLE #a(identity_column INT IDENTITY(1,1), x CHAR(1));

INSERT #a(x) VALUES('a');

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Result:

```
----
1
```

**Use the `OUTPUT` clause** if you are inserting multiple rows and need to retrieve the *set* of IDs that were generated.

```
INSERT #a(x) 
  OUTPUT inserted.identity_column 
  VALUES('b'),('c');
```

Result:

```
----
2
3
```

> and why this is best faster option?

Performance aside, these are the only ones that are guaranteed to be correct in the default isolation level and/or with multiple users. Even if you ignore the correctness aspect, SQL Server holds the inserted value in `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in memory, so naturally this will be faster than going and running your own isolated query against the table or against system tables.

Ignoring the correctness aspect is like telling the mailman he did a good job delivering today's mail - he finished his route 10 minutes faster than his average time, the problem is, none of the mail was delivered to the right house.

**Do not** use any of the following:

- `@@IDENTITY` - since this can't be used in all scenarios, for example when a table with an identity column has a trigger that also inserts into another table with its own identity column - you will get the wrong value back.
- `IDENT_CURRENT()` - I go into detail about this [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current), and the comments are useful reading as well, but essentially, under concurrency, you will often get the wrong answer.
- `MAX()` or `TOP 1` - you would have to protect the two statements with serializable isolation in order to ensure that the `MAX()` you get isn't someone else's. This is much more expensive than just using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

These functions also fail whenever you insert two or more rows, and need all the identity values generated - your only option there is the `OUTPUT` clause.

Answer (score 15):

Apart from performance, they all have rather different meanings.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will give you the last identity value inserted into *any* table *directly within the current scope* (scope = batch, stored procedure, etc. but not within, say, a trigger that was fired by the current scope).

`IDENT_CURRENT()` will give you the last identity value inserted into a specific table from *any* scope, by *any* user.

`@@IDENTITY` gives you the last identity value generated by the most recent INSERT statement for the current connection, regardless of table or scope. (Side note: Access uses this function, and thus has some issues with triggers that insert values into tables with identity columns.)

Using `MAX()` or `TOP 1` can give you entirely wrong results if the table has a negative identity step, or has had rows inserted with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` in play. Here's a script demonstrating all of these:

```
CREATE TABLE ReverseIdent (
    id int IDENTITY(9000,-1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    data char(4)
)

INSERT INTO ReverseIdent (data)
VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')

SELECT * FROM ReverseIdent

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ReverseIdent') --8998
SELECT MAX(id) FROM ReverseIdent --9000

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ReverseIdent ON

INSERT INTO ReverseIdent (id, data)
VALUES (9005, 'd')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ReverseIdent OFF

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ReverseIdent') --8998
SELECT MAX(id) FROM ReverseIdent --9005
```

Summary: stick with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, `IDENT_CURRENT()`, or `@@IDENTITY`, and make sure you're using the one that returns what you actually need.

Comment: Why do you encourage the use of `IDENT_CURRENT()` and `@@IDENTITY` when your own script demonstrates that they output incorrect results?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm not sure I follow. The last identity value generated was 8998 (notice the step is -1), and that's what `IDENT_CURRENT()` returns. MAX() never returns the right value beyond the first row, since id is counting backwards, and with `IDENTITY_INSERT` on, 9005 is not a *generated* identity value, thus not reflected by `IDENT_CURRENT()`. But it *may* return "incorrect" results if you're really after what `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns. Choose the right tool for the job.

Comment: The OP seems to be after the identity value they inserted - in this case 8998 is incorrect. The edge cases you mention (backwards increment and IDENTITY_INSERT on) even further argue *against* using IDENT_CURRENT in my opinion, and @@IDENTITY shouldn't ever really be used because of the danger of triggers (now or added later). I'm still struggling to understand why IDENT_CURRENT would be the one the OP would want to use (especially under concurrency) or why @@IDENTITY would ever be used by anyone when much more reliable methods exist.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It's not 100% clear from the question that the desired result is the last insert from the current scope (option 1 differs from 2 and 3 in that regard), so I figured it would be a good idea to describe both and how they differ. But I do agree that `@@IDENTITY` is almost never the ideal way to get generated identity values. The main point is that `MAX()` or `TOP 1` are like a less reliable version of `IDENT_CURRENT()`, which is a perfectly fine function to use if you understand what it does. Could be useful for maintenance jobs or something.